# Proper Model Category

Tags: reference-request, model-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry

Let R be a commuative ring. Consider the category of simplicial R-modules with the projective model stucture. Can someone give me a precise reference which proves that this model category is proper? Having a reference which proves other nice properties of this model category would also be good.

Answer (score 4):

I found this in Lemma 3.1.3 of http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/schwede/modelspec.pdf